# Using a print stylesheet in Safari, the orientation refers to the shape of the user's browser window rather than the orientation chosen at printing

Tags: css, printing, safari, orientation

I have tried linking to separate stylesheets based on orientation:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print and (orientation: landscape)" href="print-landscape.css">
```

and using @media queries:

```
@media print and (orientation:landscape) {}
```

But in both cases the orientation is selected based on the shape of the browser window rathen than the orientation chosen in the print menu.

Is there a way to force Safari to check orientation based on what is selected in the print menu?

I'm testing this on Safari 5.1 and have confirmed that the problem persists in newer versions.

Comment: I've got the same question....